# No boot disk has been detected or the disk has failed (Completed and easy to fix)

Tags: boot, system-installation

I have tried to load Ubuntu about 10 different times and I go through the whole setup and the last step my CD/DVD comes out and it states:

1. `Please remove installation medium, then press Enter`

   I remove disk and press Enter, then when my CPU starts back up it states:
2. `PXE-E53: No boot file name received
   PXE-M0F: Exiting PXE ROM
   ERROR: NO boot disk has been detected or the disk has failed`

I went into my BIOS settings and it says Ubuntu so I moved it to the top of the list and when it restarts it goes back to number 2 above.

This has to be some simple fix that I just can't seem to get, I am on my 2nd week of trying to get this thing to load up correctly and I am frustrated and feel out of options. Any help from someone on getting this resolved would be much appreciated. My CPU is an HP all in one, was a Windows 8.1, ram 4.00GB, 64 Bit operating system.

Comment: HP is not UEFI dual boot friendly. Sony, HP & others:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789 You now can run Boot-Repair and it will copy shimx64.efi to /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi with 'use standard EFI file advanced option. If you then already have Hard drive or fallback entry you can use that or add it. But ubuntu entry may never work with HP. https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: 1) Are you trying to dual boot? 2) As @oldfred suggests, try boot repair: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Martin, I sincerely appreciate the information you provided me with. I did the boot repair you suggested and choose the 2nd option and it went great. If you could provide your opinion on Which operating system do you prefer for security and ease of use Ubuntu or Mint? Just wondering which offers better security.